# Excess space before \[ at start of paragraph

Tags: math-mode, xetex, equations

When I have a displayed math equation (`\[`...`\]` or equivalently the `displaymath` environment) at the start of a paragraph right after a heading, there is too much space before it.

This short code reproduces the problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\section{Quadratic formula}
%Line line line line line line line line line.
\[x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\]
Line line line line line line line line line.
\end{document}
```

If the commented line is uncommented, the space around the equation becomes acceptable:

[image: Illustration of problem]

The problem does not seem to be caused by `geometry`. Repeating the above without `geometry` loaded produces this:

[image: Illustration of problem without geometry]

Using `$$`...`$$` instead (which seems to be discouraged in LaTeX) does not produce this problem:

[image: Illustration]

The problem seems to be caused by the definition of `\[` — specifically the italicised line:

```
\def\[{%
   \relax\ifmmode
      \@badmath
   \else
      \ifvmode
         \nointerlineskip
         \makebox[.6\linewidth]{}%
      \fi
      $$%%$$ BRACE MATCH HACK
   \fi
}
```

What should I do? Do I just use `$$`...`$$`? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Please give a use case for a displayed equation immediately follow a sectioning header.

Comment: @Mico The MWE I gave is more or less the same as my actual document (except that it deals with a different equation). But does it matter? If you intend to suggest that I arrange my document differently, that isn't a solution to the problem.

Comment: I bet this is for some kind of equation collection/cheat-sheet right? You wouldn't write an equation after a heading in a thesis or paper, right?

Comment: @Johannes_B Yeah, it's for my own notes on a subject. Not a formal paper.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question why there is additional space, but ... The  `section` command does some stuff you might not be aware of, generating a toc-entry, stepping counters, placing the title, adding space ... If this is for some personal notes, you can redefine section for your own needs.Of course, you are loosing some funcionality. btw, very good example and welcome to TeX.SX. :-)

Comment: btw, if you are interested, have a look at the chat transcript from a few weeks back http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20823173#20823173

Comment: @Johannes_B eh, thanks, I see now. Maybe I should load amsmath then.

Comment: Using `amsmath` when dealing with math is always a good idea. Go ahead, answer your own question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`amsmath` redefines `\[`...`\]` to its own `equation*` environment which doesn't use `\makebox` to workaround `vmode` spacing issues.

So loading `amsmath` solves this problem.

Comment: The ` amsmath` definitions ans `$$` _all_ produce bad spacing if used at the start of the paragraph, although in this case after a heading the amsmath version makes a reasonable result.